Parity eigenstates in massive $\mathcal{N}=1$ multiplet
In $\mathcal{N}=1$ SUSY we have two scalar states in the massive chiral multiplet. These are $\left|\Omega\right>$ and $\left|\Omega'\right> = \bar{Q}_1 \bar{Q}_2\left|\Omega\right>$, which satisfy
$$
Q_\alpha \left|\Omega\right> = \bar{Q}_\dot{\alpha}\left|\Omega'\right> = 0. \tag{1}
$$
Now we can introduce the parity operator $\mathcal{P}$, which satisfies
$$
\mathcal{P} P^\mu \mathcal{P}^{-1} = (P^0, -P^i),\quad \mathcal{P} Q_\alpha \mathcal{P}^{-1} = (\sigma^0)_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}} \bar{Q}^\dot{\alpha}, \quad \mathcal{P} \bar{Q}^\dot{\alpha} \mathcal{P}^{-1} = -(\sigma^0)^{\dot{\alpha}\alpha} Q_\alpha. \tag{2}
$$
From here, we can see that
$$
Q_\alpha \mathcal{P}\left|\Omega'\right> = \bar{Q}_\dot{\alpha}\mathcal{P}\left|\Omega\right> = 0, \tag{3}
$$
from which I take that $\mathcal{P}\left|\Omega'\right> \propto \left|\Omega\right>$ and $\mathcal{P}\left|\Omega\right> \propto \left|\Omega'\right>$. From here it should be possible to construct the eigenstates of $\mathcal{P}$, but I don't know how to proceed. I am guessing that they will be of the form
$$
\left|\pm\right> = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \left|\Omega\right> \pm \left|\Omega'\right> \right),
$$
but I have no idea of how to prove that there are no complex factors in between $\left|\Omega\right>$ and $\left|\Omega'\right>$.
